# Video downloading issue in android

Tags: android, video

I created 10 sec video and uploaded on amazon server and after that i  am downloading it
 within listview like image lazyloading .First time it is taking more than 6-8 minute in downloading.The video file size is  6.89-7 MB.But same video in ios taking 30 sec in 
downloading. My requirement is same like vine application in android.Please help.
Thanks in Advance .
Here is my code :-

```
public class VideoLoader {

    VideoMemoryCache memoryCache = new VideoMemoryCache();
    VideoFileCache fileCache;
    private Context context;
    private Bitmap mLoadingbmp;
    private Map<VideoView, String> imageViews = Collections
            .synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<VideoView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService;
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    public VideoLoader(Context context) {

        fileCache = new VideoFileCache(context);
        this.context = context;

        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

        mLoadingbmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                R.drawable.loading);

    }
    public void DisplayImage(String url, VideoView videoView,
            Button defaultIMage,ProgressBar progressbar) {

        imageViews.put(videoView, url);
        File bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);

        if (bitmap != null && bitmap.length()>0) {

            videoView.setVideoPath(bitmap.getAbsolutePath());
            defaultIMage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            queuePhoto(url, videoView,defaultIMage,progressbar);

            defaultIMage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, VideoView imageView,Button btn,ProgressBar pb) {
        PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView,btn,pb);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private class PhotoToLoad {
        public String url;
        public VideoView imageView;
        public Button defaultImage;
        ProgressBar progressbar;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, VideoView  i,Button btn,ProgressBar pb) {
            url = u;
            imageView = i;
            defaultImage=btn;
            progressbar=pb;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
            this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                File bmp = getFile(photoToLoad.url);

                memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);

                if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
        //      BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
        //      handler.post(bd);   

            } catch (Throwable th) {
                th.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private File getFile(String path) {
        File f = fileCache.getFile(path);

        if (f.exists())
            return f;

        try {
            if (!URLUtil.isNetworkUrl(path)) {
            } else {
                URL url = new URL(path);
                HttpURLConnection cn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                cn.setReadTimeout(5000);
                cn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
                cn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                cn.connect();
                InputStream stream = cn.getInputStream();
                if (stream == null)
                    throw new RuntimeException("stream is null");
                f.deleteOnExit();
            //  String tempPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
                byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
                do {
                    int numread = stream.read(buf);
                    if (numread <= 0)
                        break;
                    out.write(buf, 0, numread);
                } while (true);
                try {
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                    stream.close();
                    cn.disconnect();

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                }

            return f;

        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

            return null;
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {

        String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if (tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
        File bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        public BitmapDisplayer(File b, PhotoToLoad p) {
            bitmap = b;
            photoToLoad = p;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;

            try {
                if (bitmap!= null && bitmap.length()>0) {
                    photoToLoad.imageView.setVideoPath(bitmap.getAbsolutePath());
                    photoToLoad.defaultImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    photoToLoad.progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                } else {

                    photoToLoad.defaultImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    photoToLoad.progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }
```

Comment: I think the question is more suitable for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Download speed depends on many factors, including your network bandwidth, device/sd card write speed, etc. You are using single-threaded download with small data buffer that affects download performance. I would recommend increasing your data buffer size from 1024 to 8192 or higher and implement multi-threaded downloads (in case your server supports it). See HTTP "Range" header for details.